# Change LinearLayout height to 0 programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am resizign `LinearLayout` from it's original height to `0` with:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
params.height = newHeight;
requestLayout();
```

Everything works except `newHeight = 0` - layout's height changes back to its original height. How can I avoid it ?

Setting visibility to `GONE` if `newHeight == 0` does not help.

Comment: why do you rezise it to 0? do you want to hide it?

Comment: I am resizing it for handling drag&drop behavior. User slides below item and hides above layout.

Comment: params.height = 0? else, view.GONE is a nice way to hide things.

Comment: I did that, layout's content is not visible, however height is going back to the original value so I have 40dp empty space.

Comment: setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ?

Comment: does it goes to 0 and then back to its original? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: Even if I hardcode `params.height = 0` and call `requestLayout` it goes back to its original height defined in xml.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this.....

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = 0;
```

Comment: Specifing view with id works well, it is able to set `0` height. Thanks !

Comment: And, if i have to set it to say "match_parent" then how can it be done?

Comment: lp.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

Answer (score 3):

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearTop);

layout.getLayoutParams().height =  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;                
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =    layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height =  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Please add a description of how this solves the users question. Also, please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to set the height of `params` using [setBaseAttributes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#setBaseAttributes%28android.content.res.TypedArray,%20int,%20int%29)? The `int height = ...` will not have any influence on `params`...

Comment: Ah, I have edited my code - it should be `params.height = newHeight`. Sorry. However problem is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you get the actual parameters object, not the copy of one?
I would try the following code:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
params.height = newHeight;
setLayoutParams(params);
requestLayout();
```

Comment: If you `requestLayout`, you can modify params from `getLayoutParams`. Otherwise you have to `setLayoutParams`. For every other than `0` value it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a new layout params object then. This should work

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: It also sets original height. If I set `1` instead of `0` - height is changed well to `1`.