# How to I make my android table have rows of equal heights?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want my table to have every row be the same height and not depend on what the textview contains. I have tried some suggestions to similar requests but I couldn't get any of them to work. If the textview doesn't have text in it, its height is smaller than the textviews with text in them. This is part of a timetable app so some textviews will get text assigned to them but I want them all to look the same regardless. If you need any more information just ask. I hope this is not too vague
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TableLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="6"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:text="@string/time"
                        android:id="@+id/lblTime"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="@string/dayOne"
                        android:id="@+id/lblDayOne"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="@string/dayTwo"
                        android:id="@+id/lblDayTwo"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="@string/dayThree"
                        android:id="@+id/lblDayThree"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="@string/dayFour"
                        android:id="@+id/lblDayFour"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="@string/dayFive"
                        android:id="@+id/lblDayFive"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="6"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="9:00"
                        android:id="@+id/lblPeriodOne"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:gravity="left|center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/M9"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/Tue9"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/W9"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:id="@+id/Thur9"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/F9"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="6"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:text="10:00"
                        android:id="@+id/lblPeriodTwo"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:gravity="left|center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/M10"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:id="@+id/Tue10"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/W10"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/Thur10"
                        android:layout_column="5"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="20dip"
                        android:id="@+id/F10"
                        android:layout_column="6"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do that programmatically.

[Change LinearLayout height to 0 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245371/change-linearlayout-height-to-0-programmatically)

In this question you will find how to do that. And the main idea is to add all the rows you need to a list, get all of theirs heights and find a max of those (if I understood what you wanted to do). Then you just make all other rows the same height

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see in your Layout XML, all of your Table Rows have same height as `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` Instead of that you should give a constant value if you want to have them all with same height.

Try this instead : `android:layout_height="100dp"` and see if it makes sense.